# Is date published a predefined function in Django?

Tags: python, django

class Question(models.Model):

```
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

In the above code, how pub_date is getting the exact date?

Comment: be more specific regarding the doubt.

Comment: See here pub_date is giving the exact date.My question is how so? Is 'date published ' predefined in such a way it gets exact date?

Comment: What you mean by *"... pub_date is giving the exact date."*. I don't get that.

Comment: In the above model pub_date is giving the date the question was published.How it is working like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes predefined in the [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library, both version 2 and 3.